Relative entropy and finite second moment bound
Suppose that $\nu$ is a probability measure (say on $\mathbb{R}$) with finite second moment. Let $\mu$ be another probability measure. Suppose that $KL(\mu \mid \nu)<\infty$. Does this then imply that $\mu$ has finite second moment as well?

Certainly not. Take $\mu$ as a Cauchy distribution and $\nu$ a Gaussian one.

Example doesn't quite work: with $\mu = \frac{C}{1+x^2}dx, \nu = D e^{-x^2}dx$, we get $\mathrm{KL}(\mu|\nu) = \int \frac{1}{1+x^2} (x^2 - \log(1+x^2) + \log(C/D)) = \infty. $

But, you can take $\mu(dx) \propto \frac{1}{1+|x|^3} dx$ and $\nu(dx) \propto e^{-|x|}dx$

Oupss! Now, in your example $Ce^{-\sqrt{|x|}}$ seems better.

If you fix your main answer I will accept it.
